# AWS Lambda tmp disk limit with ffmpeg

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, ffmpeg

I am using AWS Lambda to render videos using ffmpeg. It is a basic function that downloads external clips, merges those, then uploads the result to S3.

This function needs to be able to scale quickly because I need to generate a lot of videos in a short time period.

The problem is that I reach the `/tmp` disk limit of 512MB because the same lambda environment is reused by the different requests. I have increased that memory limit to temporarily solve the problem but it does not feel scalable.

I have looked into EFS but the requirement to use a VPC and a NAT to have internet access sounds really heavy for my simple needs.

Is there a way to output the result of ffmpeg directly in S3 (thus not needing the temporary folder)? Or perhaps force to respawn a clean lambda environment if the memory is about to be full?

Comment: Note that /tmp is disk, not memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [AWS Lambda Now Supports Up to 10 GB Ephemeral Storage](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/):

> AWS Lambda now allows you to configure ephemeral storage (/tmp) between 512 MB and 10,240 MB. You can now control the amount of ephemeral storage a function gets for reading or writing data, allowing you to use AWS Lambda for ETL jobs, ML inference, or other data-intensive workloads.

Note that each invocation of your Lambda function can safely remove files that are present in `/tmp` - you will never have two concurrent Lambda invocations using the same runtime environment. Any files present there are left over from a prior, now complete, invocation of the Lambda function. If there's no need to share files from one Lambda invocation to the next, then your Lambda function can delete those files before exiting to ensure the next invocation has a clean `/tmp` folder.

Comment: The latter part of this answer is what I'd go for: have each lambda clean up after itself, and you won't need to pay for more storage :)

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver Agree that cleaning up before exit is a sound choice, assuming there is no legitimate caching use case for content shared across warm-start Lambda invocations. Lambda ephemeral storage, however, is charged by the amount you allocate to the function, not how much is in use at any given point in time.

Comment: In my case, I do clean up on exit but I think because the other invocations are not finished (rendering the video can take up to 2 minutes), that's why the /tmp dir is not empty. Is that safe to remove the files? Won't it affect the running lambda?

Comment: No, each lambda currently running will have its own execution environment, at no point will two running lambdas see the same /tmp folder.  It's generally more efficient to clean up at start, since cleaning up at end might waste time cleaning up for a run that'll never happen.

Comment: All right thanks! I'll try that